# Android : Show webview only once when the application is running

Tags: android, webview, sharedpreferences

I have a `WebView` that will show in fullscreen when I run the Activity.

I want that `WebView` only open just once everytime I open the application.

So if I close the application, then I start again it will show the `WebView`. 
But when i close the `webView`, go to another activity, and then back to the activity that have a same `Webview` ,the `WebView` won't show again.Unless until I restart the application.

How to do something like that? I already search it and its looks like I can use the `SharedPreferences`, but most of them used it for a single activity.
Can I use it for a single `WebView`?

Comment: Sure. You have to put the logic into the hosting fragment/activity and check if the application has shown the webview. At app start reset the property.

Comment: @schlingel How to reset the property? Maybe a clue how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store some value in some variable of `sharedpreference`. When user open your app,a check of the value of that variable every time will happen by retrieving it from `sharedpreference` . Let the variable be `boolean`, and the value retrieved is `true`,then edit this value and change it to `false`.While navigating through your app,nothing will hapeen to this variable's value.Even if the first `activity` on which you displayed a webview is reopened in someway because the variable needs to be true to get your webview code executed (which you can accomplish by loading webview in an if statement checking your variable's value),but when `oncreate` is called and it will check for that variable it will find t as `false`. When ever user closes your application then again change that variable to true in the `sharedpreferences` .And on next login to your app,the `webview` will be loaded

```
 SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("isItFirstTime", true);
    editor.commit();
```

the you can get it as:

```
 SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("your_prefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
 Boolean myValue = sp.getBoolean("isFirstTime", false);
```

also see this [How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Comment: Do Tell me if any issue arises